# Blue lines coming out of vertices

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image][image: blue lines]

Hello,

I clicked something and these blue lines appeared. How do I hide them?
The lines are coming out of the vertices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like these are the Normals of your object vertices.

Since 2.8 it's in the *Viewport Overlays* panel (top right of your 3D view):

[image]

Until 2.7, display the right panel with <kbd>N</kbd> > *Mesh Display* > *Normals* and disable the *Display Vertex* button:

[image]

Comment: i dont know if im just blind but I can't seem to find that button in the `n` menu nor the `properties` panel. would you be able to add a 2.8+ image of where to find this toggle? @moonboots

Comment: I've edited, it's now in the Viewport Overlays panel